# Create a dictionary that contains student name, roll no and marks obtained

Tags: python

I did a program to create a dictionary that contains student name, roll no and marks obtained.When I execute it to form multiple dictionaries instead of one.
This is the code:

```py
def student(x,y,z):
   result = {}
   result[roll_no] = [std_name, marks]
   print(result)


n = int(input("Enter No of Students:"))
for i in range(n):

   roll_no = int(input("Roll No: "))
   std_name = input("Student Name: ")
   marks = int(input("Marks: "))
   student(std_name, roll_no, marks)
```

Comment: What is your question/problem?

Comment: your student function takes x,y,z and you use variables from main function?

Comment: @MichaelButscher The Question/Problem is to create a dictionary that contains student name, roll no and marks obtained

Comment: x,y,z are positional arguments that is getting replaced by std_name, roll no, marks

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the result every time, you have to define the result before the loop

```
def students(n):
    result = {}
    for _ in range(n):
        roll_no = int(input("Roll No: "))
        std_name = input("Student Name: ")
        marks = int(input("Marks: "))
        result[roll_no] = [std_name, marks]
    print(result)

n = int(input("Enter No of Students:"))
students(n)
```